# Zero sets for entire functions $f$ with $|f(z)| \leq C_f e^{c|z|}$

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Let $c>0$ and $X$ the collection of all entire functions $f$ for which there exists $C_f > 0$ s.t.
$$
|f(z)| \leq C_f e^{c|z|}.
$$
Given a sequence $(z_n) \subset (0,\infty)$ s.t.
$$
\frac {z_n}{n} \geq \frac \pi c, \quad \forall n
$$
my question is whether $(z_n)$ is contained in the zero set of a non-trivial function in $X$. The question is motivated by theorems I read on completeness problems of complex exponentials. I have the feeling that the above claim is true and could be found in some book. Does someone have a reference for it or an easy proof/disproof?

Comment: if say $c=\pi$ and $z_n=n$ then if $f$ has zeroes precisely at $z_n$ then $f(z) \Gamma (-z+1)$ is entire and has no zeroes so is $e^g$ and $1/\Gamma$ has maximal type so is not in $X$ hence $f$ is not in $X$; you need some symmetry for the zeroes to conclude a result of the type you want - see Levin Lectures on Entire Functions page $32$

Comment: Thank you! Perhaps the notion of zero set I defined is a bit uncommon, for me it does not mean that $f$ has to vanish only on $Z$, but it is some nontrivial function with $Z$ a subset of the zero set (I edited the post). If ones assumes a symmetry in the zeros as you stated, is there some reference for a result of the above type?

Comment: The book by Levin (Lectures on Entire Functions) has results in this direction- here the result should be easy since the function that has zeroes at $\pm z_n$, has Hadamard product without any exponential term since one can group them in pairs and $f(z)=\Pi (1-z^2/z_n^2)$ converges absolutely as $\sum 1/z_n^2$ does; this should imply that the type of $f$ is equal to the upper density of the zeroes so is at most $c$

Comment: No. Lindelof's theorem says that $\lim_{R\to\infty} \sum_{|z_n|\le R} 1/z_n$ exists for the zeros of an entire function of exponential type. Obviously, the condition can fail in your setting. See Koosis, The logarithmic integral I, Section III B.

Comment: But since I'm only interested in function whose zero set contains $(z_n)$, I could in principle consider functions with a symmetric zero set and hope to be in the desired class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As in [Conrad's comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/455530/zero-sets-for-entire-functions-f-with-fz-leq-c-f-ecz#comment1179376_455530), let
$$f(z):=\prod_1^\infty\Big(1-\frac{z^2}{z_n^2}\Big).$$
Then for complex $z\ne0$
$$|f(z)|=\prod_1^\infty\Big|1-\frac{z^2}{z_n^2}\Big|
\le\prod_1^\infty\Big(1+\frac{|z|^2}{z_n^2}\Big)\le\prod_1^\infty\Big(1+\frac{c^2|z|^2}{\pi^2 n^2}\Big)
=\frac{\sinh c|z|}{c|z|}\le e^{c|z|},$$
as desired.